# What is the word for someone who doesn't like to do anything?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I sometimes ask my brother if I can get a ride to work or tell him to move, but he always tells me "no" or waves me off. He also does the same thing when he is told to do something, like when he is told to do the dish or do the laundry; he says "no" or just ignores the person.

Comment: I believe the word for this is teenager.

Comment: What's wrong with *lazy*?

Answer (score 0):

Simple: he is a **do-nothing person**.

Comment: Can you cite some examples where this phrase is used?

Answer (score 0):

**Avolition** is the psychiatric term.

**DSM V** for mental disorders

Comment: Have you got a source for this?

Answer (score 0):

none of these are necessarily right, but...

a jerk

a cold-hearted curmudgeon

a selfish person

a libertarian

not a team player

obstinate

uncooperative

or just a lazy bastard

Comment: If you are unsure what the asker is looking for, a better way is to request clarification in a comment on the question. Notions, trial balloons, offhand ideas, or guesses are not answers. A good expert answer answers the question and includes explanation, context, and supporting facts.

Answer (score 0):

I would think such a person is a ***naysayer***:

> one who denies, refuses, opposes, or is skeptical or cynical about something ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naysayer))

e.g.

> Many people pitied my commonsensical, public-spirited child for being raised by an antisocial naysayer like me. ([WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/naysayer.html))

Answer (score -1):

Consider,

***grinch***

> : (*AmEng*) a person whose lack of enthusiasm or bad temper has a depressing effect on others
>   [C20: from a character in the 1957 children's book How the Grinch stole Christmas by Dr Seuss (1904-91), US writer and illustrator, whose full name was Theodor Seuss Geisel] [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Grinch)

***wet blanket***.

> : a person who makes it difficult for other people to enjoy themselves by complaining, by showing no enthusiasm, etc. [M-W](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wet%20blanket)

Comment: Also, "stick-in-the-mud", for someone who never wants to be part of a group activity.

Comment: @HotLicks A stick-in-the-mud for me is more like someone who resists change. http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stick-in-the-mud